# Remove Auth Filter on one of the Web API's in spring-boot

Tags: authentication, spring-security, spring-boot

My project has 2 API's. 1st requires Authentication and the 2nd one does not.

I was successfully able to added a Token Based Auth Filter for the first API `/auth/uploadFile`

Here is the code snippet from the **SecurityConfig** class which **extends** **WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter**.

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class).authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/auth/uploadFile/").permitAll().anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().csrf().disable();
    }
```

I **haven't** added my second API `/noauth/uploadFile` to the **antMatchers()** but it still enters the custom **tokenAuthenticationFilter** when I make a POST call to it.

How can I avoid entering my custom filter **tokenAuthenticationFilter**  when I make a call to my second API `/noauth/uploadFile` i.e my filter should not be applied on the second API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override/add below method in SecurityConfig  class.

```
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
        .ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/noauth/**");
}
```